# Rails-data association one to many (undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, foreign-key-relationship

I need help on the following error:

> undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass

It happened after I added some data association with my table:

```
    class Crew < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :Peme, :foreign_key => pemeid, :dependent => destroy
        has_many :Training, :foreign_key => trgid, :dependent => destroy
        has_many :Visa, :foreign_key => visaid, :dependent => destroy
        has_many :Contract, :foreign_key => contid, :dependent => destroy
        has_many :FlagEndorsement, :foreign_key => flgendoid, :dependent => destroy
        has_many :Seminar, :foreign_key => semid, :dependent => destroy
    end

   Class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
       attr_accessible :contcost, :contdate, :contid, :contremarks, :conttype, :crewid
       belongs_to :Crew, :foreign_key => "crewid"
   end
   class FlagEndorsement < ActiveRecord::Base
       attr_accessible :crewid, :flgendocost, :flgendodate, :flgendoid, :flgendoremarks, :flgendotype
        belongs_to :Crew, :foreign_key => "crewid"
  end
  class Peme < ActiveRecord::Base
       attr_accessible :crewid, :pemecost, :pemedate, :pemeid, :pemeremarks, :pemetype
       belongs_to :Crew, :foreign_key => "crewid"
  end
 Class Seminar < ActiveRecord::Base
       attr_accessible :crewid, :semcost, :semdate, :semid, :semremarks
       belongs_to :Crew, :foreign_key => "crewid"
 end
 Class Training < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :crewid, :trgcost, :trgdate, :trgid, :trgremarks, :trgtype
      belongs_to :Crew, :foreign_key => "crewid"
 end
 class Visa < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :crewid, :visacost, :visadate, :visaid, :visaremarks, :visatype
   belongs_to :Crew, :foreign_key => "crewid"
end
```

I want to be peme, training, visa, flgendorsements, seminar to be a dependent to crew
But what would I should do?

Answer (score 1):

**1**. Get your upper/lower-case sorted. `has_many` must be followed by a **pluralized** association name in **underscore** form, like this:

```
has_many :flag_endorsements
```

**2**. Get your symbols right:

```
    :foreign_key => pemeid, :dependent => destroy
```

This instead of setting `:foreign_key` to `:pemeid` and `:dependent` to `:destroy` will look for value of local variables `pemeid` and `dependent`. if local variables don't exist it will try to call methods `pemeid` and `dependent` that don't exist as well. And the second you define those methods somewhere for entirely different purpose you're in debugging hell.

**3**. Get your naming conventions right. `crewid` is terrible name for attribute/column. It must be `crew_id`. Same goes about literally every attribute/column you specified. Please read some basic tutorials about rails where everyone explicitly says how good it is to follow conventions and how rails is built around conventions and if you don't follow them your rails stuff will simply not work.

After you finish cleaning up your code - provide the full exception trace (if something is still broken) and then someone might help you.